# Alteração Dinâmica da JSP no JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, jboss

Olá.

Quanto estou trabalhando com JSP eu acho muito ruim ter que pausar e iniciar a aplicação toda vez que precisar ver uma alteração. Tem alguma forma de atualizar as alterações da pagina sem fazer tudo isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma modificação para utilizar HotDeploy no Jboss 7 também.

Essa configuração fica no arquivo jboss-service.xml localizado na pasta conf/ da partição (all/default/etc) utilizada...

Abaixo segue um trecho do arquivo onde é especificado as configurações de scanning.

```
<!-- ==================================================================== -->  
<!-- Deployment Scanning                                                  -->  
<!-- ==================================================================== -->  

<!-- An mbean for hot deployment/undeployment of archives.  
-->  
<mbean code="org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner"  
name="jboss.deployment:type=DeploymentScanner,flavor=URL">  

<!-- Uncomment (and comment/remove version below) to enable usage of the  
 DeploymentCache  
<depends optional-attribute-    name="Deployer">jboss.deployment:type=DeploymentCache</depends>  
-->  
 <depends optional-attribute-name="Deployer">jboss.system:service=MainDeployer</depends>  

 <!-- The URLComparator can be used to specify a deployment ordering  
    for deployments found in a scanned directory.  The class specified  
    must be an implementation of java.util.Comparator, it must be able  
    to compare two URL objects, and it must have a no-arg constructor.  
    Two deployment comparators are shipped with JBoss:  
      - org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentSorter  
        Sorts by file extension, as follows:  
          "sar", "service.xml", "rar", "jar", "war", "wsr", "ear", "zip",  
          "*"  
      - org.jboss.deployment.scanner.PrefixDeploymentSorter  
        If the name portion of the url begins with 1 or more digits, those  
        digits are converted to an int (ignoring leading zeroes), and  
        files are deployed in that order.  Files that do not start with  
        any digits will be deployed first, and they will be sorted by  
        extension as above with DeploymentSorter.  
  -->  
  <attribute name="URLComparator">org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentSorter</attribute>  

  <!--  
  <attribute    name="URLComparator">org.jboss.deployment.scanner.PrefixDeploymentSorter</attribute>  
   -->  

  <!-- The FilterInstance specifies a URLLister.URLFilter for scanned  
    directories. This DeploymentFilter is initialized with the given  
    prefixes, suffixes and matches that define which URLs should be  
    ignored.  
  -->  
  <attribute name="FilterInstance"  
  attributeClass="org.jboss.deployment.scanner.DeploymentFilter"  
  serialDataType="javaBean">  
  <!-- Files starting with theses strings are ignored -->  
  <property name="prefixes">#,%,\,,.,_$</property>  
  <!-- Files ending with theses strings are ignored -->  
  <property name="suffixes">#,$,%,~,\,v,.BAK,.bak,.old,.orig,.tmp,.rej,.sh</property>  
  <!-- Files matching with theses strings are ignored -->  
  <property     name="matches">.make.state,.nse_depinfo,CVS,CVS.admin,RCS,RCSLOG,SCCS,TAGS,core,tags</prope     rty>  
  </attribute>  

 <!-- Frequency in milliseconds to rescan the URLs for changes -->  
 <attribute name="ScanPeriod">5000</attribute>  

 <!-- A flag to disable the scans -->  
 <attribute name="ScanEnabled">true</attribute>  

<!-- URLs are comma separated and resolve relative to the server home URL  
  unless the given path is absolute. If the URL ends in "/" it is  
  considered a collection and scanned, otherwise it is simply deployed;  
  this follows RFC2518 convention and allows discrimination between  
  collections and directories that are simply unpacked archives.  

  URLs may be local (file:) or remote (http:). Scanning is supported  
  for remote URLs but unpacked deployment units are not.  

  Example URLs:  
     deploy/  
          scans ${jboss.server.url}/deploy/, which is local or remote  
          depending on the URL used to boot the server  
     ${jboss.server.home}/deploy/  
          scans ${jboss.server.home}/deploy, which is always local  
     file:/var/opt/myapp.ear  
          deploy myapp.ear from a local location  
     file:/var/opt/apps/  
          scans the specified directory  
     http://www.test.com/netboot/myapp.ear  
          deploys myapp.ear from a remote location  
     http://www.test.com/netboot/apps/  
          scans the specified WebDAV location  
  -->  
  <attribute name="URLs">  
    deploy/  
  </attribute>  

  <!-- Indicates if the scanner should recursively scan directories that  
  contain no "." in their names. This can be used to group applications  
  and services that must be deployed and that have the same  
  logical function in the same directory i.e.  
  deploy/JMX/  
  deploy/JMS/  
  ...  
 -->  
  <attribute name="RecursiveSearch">True</attribute>  

</mbean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Faça um deploy explodido (ou seja, com uma pasta e não o war / ear). Como fazer isso depende do seu mecanismo de deploy e tipo de artefato. Para um projeto web gerenciado pelo maven por exemplo você faria isso com `mvn war:exploded`. Eu também precisei alterar meu *build* para que a pasta gerada termine em `.war`, mas não sei se isso é específico da minha versão do JBoss.

```
projeto/target/meu-war-versao.war/
```

Adicionalmente boa parte dos IDEs podem ser configurados para atualizar os recursos ao salvar (estou usando o IDEA, mas sei que o Netbeans também faz isso, e acredito que o Eclipse também). Dessa forma você não precisa nem invocar o comando no maven para atualizar os recursos.

Finalmente, a mágica acontece nas suas configurações. Se você utiliza o JBoss 7 em modo *standalone*, altere o arquivo `standalone.xml` e adicione a seguinte configuração:

```
<configuration>
   <jsp-configuration development="true" check-interval="1" modification-test-interval="1" recompile-on-fail="true"/>
</configuration>
```

Dentro da tag `subsystem` (`xmlns=":urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1"`).

**Atenção**: Conforme [esse post na comunidade do JBoss](https://community.jboss.org/thread/202446?start=0&tstart=0) existe um bug na versão 7.1.1 que impede o *hot deploy*, use a versão 7.1.2 ou superior.